# Vuejs drag sort items and save to mongoDB with Axios

Tags: mongodb, vue.js, vuejs3

I am beginner and my goal is to fetch items from DB, drag and sort them, and then save that sorted list in my DB. I have managed to fetch and set up drag sort vuejs component and I get key pair values of sorted items, but I don't know hot to save it to db.

When I execute saveNewSequence, I get console log value from forEach and nothing else, but when I refresh my page I get error: request aborted. And my list is not updated in DB.... I believe I have to somehow connect key value with id...  can you please help.

Vue component:

```
data() {
    return {
      ropes: [],

    }
  },

methods:{

     saveNewSequence() {
      this.ropes.forEach((rope, key)=>{
        console.log('Key' + key +' '+ rope._id)
      })

      let postData = {}
      postData.ropes = this.ropes.map(rope=>{
        return{
          title: rope.title,
          description:rope.description,
          image: rope.image,
          price: rope.price,
          cartQuantity: rope.cartQuantity

        }
      })
      axios.post('https://zokadb.herokuapp.com/api/ropes', postData)
          .then((res) => {
            console.log(res)

          }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })


    },

}
```

this is my mongoDB model:

```
const ropeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,

    },

    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true,

    },
    image: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
    },


    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,

    },
    cartQuantity: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },


    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
})
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you running into issues or errors?

Comment: Here is my Trello app, build in Vue.js using as well D&D
see the github repo to look for the source code if you'd like
------------------------
trellex.herokuapp.com
----------------------
https://github.com/Avivbens/trellex-proj-sprint4-public

Comment: @AvivBenShahar, well when i execute saveNewSequence, i get console log value from forEach and nothing else, but when i refresh my page i get error: request aborted. and my list is not updated in DB....